# iphone UIScrollView reverse order positioning

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, reverse

I'm building an app based upon the "Scrolling" sample code that Apple provided. All is working very well. The nature of the images that I want to display, would make it desirable, if the order of the images is reversed, and that the first visible image is the right-most, rather than the left most. Basically, the user should scroll back, from right to left, rather than from left to right.
But now: I don't understand the syntax Apple is using, and I hope someone can explain to me what is going on. Here are the relevant parts of the sample app:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
    NSUInteger i;
    for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
        rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
        imageView.frame = rect;
        imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
        [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }

    [self layoutScrollImages];  // now place the photos in serial layout within the scrollview

}

- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
    UIImageView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

    // reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
    CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
            view.frame = frame;

            curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
        }
    }

    // set the content size so it can be scrollable
    [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
}
```

Comment: What part of the syntax do you have trouble with?

Comment: It's basically the CG-related stuff. I tried just to change "for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)" into "for (i = kNumImages; i => 1; i--)", but in the context of my app, that delivered unexpected results. 
Beyond that, it doesn't solve my problem on how to show the last right-most 'frame'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I ended up doing:
I first inverted the order of the subviews, and then I made the scrollview jump to the last 'frame', by adding the following lines:

```
CGPoint lastFrame = CGPointMake(((kNumImages -1) * kScrollObjWidth), 0.0f);
[scrollview setContentOffset:lastFrame];
```

I hope that this somehow is useful to somebody...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to modify layoutScrollImages.  Initialize curXLoc to the max number needed, and decrement it in the loop.

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
    UIImageView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

    // reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
    CGFloat curXLoc = kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth;
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
                CGRect frame = view.frame;
                frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
                view.frame = frame;

                curXLoc -= (kScrollObjWidth);
        }
    }

    // set the content size so it can be scrollable
    [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, and since I'm still trying to understand what's going on in this part of the code, I'm not able to troubleshoot either.

I'm a bit closer to the solution though: I just reverted the order of the subviews somewhere else in the code.

The only thing left now, is to have the scrollView1 the last, rather than the first subview.